raspberry pi running apache2 - attempting to get SSL / HTTPS running
I'm in a pickle trying to get HTTPS working on raspberry PI with apache2.
I am getting unresponsive queries to HTTPS and in my apache2 error log, I am receiving "AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024 (OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023), version currently loaded is 0x300000B0) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior" error.
I've seen previous history of this same error on various forums, but have not rectified what steps I need to take.
The following apt install commands were performed:
apache2, openssl, php, libapache2-mod-php, mariadb-server, php-mysql, phpMyAdmin, php-mbstring, php-xml, php-gd, apache2, mariadb-server, libapache2-mod-php, php-gd php-curl, openssl, php-imagick, php-intl, php-json, php-ldap, php-common, php-mbstring, php-mysql, php-imap, php-sqlite3, php-net-ftp, php-zip, unzip, php-pgsql, php-ssh2, php-xml
HTTPS queries to server are timing out.
This is running with a Let's Encrypt setup.
Router is running 80 / 443 forwarded to 8080 / 8443 respectively.
My /etc/apache2 config file in sites-enabled:
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName <my domain is listed here> 
        ServerAdmin <my email is listed here>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all
        ServerName <my domain is listed here>
        ServerAdmin <my email is listed here>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain>/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain>/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain>/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>

ports.conf has both 8080/8443 listed for LISTEN.
I think the apparent incompatibility between openssl & mod_ssl is the primary problem that needs addressing. what steps can I take? I'm not a pro on reverting things to older versions when it comes to this OS and understand there are many dependencies that must be addressed/considered.
Researched for OpenSSL 3.0.13 from apt, no results found.
